# Is there a way to forward a page from proxy in nginx?

Tags: angularjs, http, nginx, forward

I configure a reverse proxy in my nginx.conf, and it works very well.

```
location /foo/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_redirect   off;
}
```

and I also handle the error request:

```
location @404 {
    #redirect to http://localhost:5000/foo/index.html
    return 302 /foo/index.html; 
}
error_page 404 = @404;
```

As you can see, I use 302 to redirect to the index.html. also works perfectly so far.

But what I want is not redirect. I want to forward the index page to browser.
(the reason I need forward is I want to handle the refresh problem when I enable the html5mode and remove the `#` in angularjs app.)

So is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `error_page 404 = /foo/index.html;`?

Comment: @Sergio, I tried your solution, it just works! oh, thank you very much!

Comment: @yukuan: huh? I didn't propose anything, did I? :)

Comment: @Sergio, sorry to confuse you #_#. It's Richard's solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your named location is forcing a redirect. The `error_page` handling does not require a redirect. You can specify a local URI in the `error_page` statement, that is handled by your proxy location:

For example:

```
location /foo/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    proxy_redirect   off;
}
error_page 404 = /foo/index.html;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for more.